# Trigger a Jenkins build on Azure Blob update

Tags: azure, jenkins, notifications

Previously I had created an automation job for AWS where Jenkins keeps an eye on an SQS queue using the Jenkins AWS SQS Plugin and triggers a build job when it finds a message in the queue. The queue is configured to receive notification from an S3 Bucket whenever any "create" event occurs.

I am trying to test out a similar process on Microsoft Azure platform and am a little confused as to which Azure services to use. I see that Azure Event Grid can be used or maybe we can directly post notification from Blob Storage service or maybe use Azure Service Bus ?!?

Also, I did found a [Jenkins Azure Storage plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Windows+Azure+Storage+Plugin) which has a slightly different but useful functionality.

As for documentation, I found only one [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/8cumct/triggering_a_jenkins_pipeline_from_azure_storage/) that is close to how this might be done but that too seems incomplete..

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Functions for it. Write a code that will be triggered when a new blob arrives / existing blob gets updated, then do a request to your jenkins to queue a build.

Here are useful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API