# Trigger Jenkins Pipeline when new file gets added to blob storage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, azure-blob-storage

I've an Azure blob storage bucket with some video files.I need to trigger a Jenkins Pipeline whenever a file gets added to the bucket. I was thinking I could have a microservice in the Azure Functions to monitor the bucket and trigger Jenkins but it would be great if I could do this directly without an additional microservice.
Is there a way I can get Jenkins to trigger a pipeline based on my bucket? A plugin or a script or something?
PS: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400293/trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-azure-blob-update), but I'm looking for something different.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a build without parameters by [setting up an event subscription on your storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview) to call your Jenkins build endpoint. Since your build won't have parameters, your script would have to keep track of the blobs processed (assuming they are not deleted once processed).

***But if you need build parameters*** then you would have to transform the payload coming from the blob event before calling the Jenkins API.

*Though you mentioned that you wouldn't want to include another service for this, sharing options just in case,* in increasing order of complexity

1. If you have your Jenkins API behind an API Gateway, like [Azure APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts), you could [transform the body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) before forwarding the request to Jenkins.
2. Use a simple [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) to trigger on the event and then call the Jenkins API, passing the parameters extracted from the event as required
3. Similar to what is mentioned in the other question you linked, [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview).

If you don't have APIM (or something similar), Logic Apps are a great solution considering the use case with almost no-code to write.